# Selecting specific control points on a mesh when using box selection

Tags: selection-tools

Is it possible to select vertices/edges/faces that the selection only touched
not all of the them?

Comment: Do you want to unselect some of the elements that have been selected using box select`?

Comment: Are you looking for deselect all? That would be the A key by default.

Comment: no.When i click b on edges i need to select 2 vertices to select an edge. is it possible to select the edge just by moving over him?

Comment: Probably you should press C instead of B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an edge you should switch to edge select mode and right click on the edge or by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. To select more edges hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing <kbd>RMB</kbd>.

[image]

See [Documentation on Selecting](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Selecting)